# How to return previous cell value after iterative change into a new cell

Tags: excel, vba

Typically, I am good a getting around using the VBA module since I am not a programmer, but I think this problem may require it. What I want to do is create a function or macro that will read the "current" r^2 value off a chart and dump that value into a new cell called "previous" whenever the data updates and the r^2 value changes. In other words I want the excel file to show both the current active r^2 value from the chart and the previous r^2 value before the change into two separate cells.

I am using the function `=1-SUMPRODUCT((C3:C12-(D3:D12*INDEX(LINEST(C3:C12,D3:D12,NOT(F$5)),1)+INDEX(LINEST(C3:C12,D3:D12,NOT(F$5)),2)))^2)/SUMPRODUCT((C3:C12-AVERAGE(C3:C12))^2)` to read the active scatter plot and output the r^2 value.

This is the closest result I could fine online: [How do I get the old value of a changed cell in Excel VBA?](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/how-do-i-get-the-old-value-of-a-changed-%20%20cell-in-excel-vba.21275/)

Image of my workbook:
 [image: R^2 comparison]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy the cell into another cell before updating the graph.

```
'Transfer the current value to the previous value cell
cells(11,7) = cells(10,7).value
'Refresh the sheet. (or do whatever it is you need to do to update the graph.
Application.Calculate
```